# Jquery css change issue

Tags: jquery, css

Simply, I want to change the css display state of a div based on what you select on a drop down. That means, when I select an item on my drop down, it changes a div's css `display` property from `none` to `block`.

My CSS

```
<style>
  .lp_claims, .gap_claims, .home_claims, .motor_claims{ display:none;}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<select name="claimsform">
<option value="lp_claims"> Loan Protection </option>
 <option value="gap_claims"> GAP or Cash Assist </option>
 <option value="home_claims"> Home </option>
 <option value="land_claims"> Landlords </option>
<option value="motor_claims"> Car </option>
</select> 

<div class="lp_claims">
<p> <strong>Loan </strong><br>
Contact  us  </p>
</div>

<div class="gap_claims">
<p> <strong>GAP or Cash Assist </strong><br>
Contact  us  </p></div>

<div class="home_claims">
<p><strong>Home </strong><br>
Contact  us  .</p>
</div>

<div class="motor_claims">
<p><strong>Motor</strong><br>
Contact  us .</p>
</div>
```

and Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').on('change', function(){
var val = $(this).val();
$('div').hide();
$('.' + val).css('display','block'); }).change();
});
</script>
```

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/En4Ka/

**OK NOW EVERYTHING WORKS FINE. AND MY QUESTION IS : Why isnt this working on my HTML file : http://fitfixtraining.com.au/test/index.html**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because (as ahren [+1] said) you have an illegal character in your code, look at your console's errors.

It usually happens when you copypasta code from jsfiddle.

Here's a screenshot from [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) where I highlight it for you:

[image]

**edit:** Just coded a quick JS to get rid of those pesky invisible white spaces, you can try it [here](http://jsbin.com/alefal/12).

Comment: Actually, it's just the illegal character that's wrong -- there's some hidden unicode there that's breaking the browser. He's closing the event closure and the ready closure correctly.

Comment: Damn that indentation! Heh had to read it another 2 times. Thanks @brianpeiris

Comment: I updated the link but it still doenst work. : http://www.fitfixtraining.com.au/test/index.html

Comment: @Uds There's still an invalid character in the same place it was before. `=]`

Comment: Whats the best way to strip out invalid characters?

Comment: I use notepad++ as linked in the answer for it, but for your user case, just click in the end of the line and press backspace once. `:P` Updated the screenshot with the new code as well.

Comment: Using [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) also tells you in which line the invalid characters are at, but for a tool to remove those, I can't think of any besides maybe a regex search and replace. Perhaps I should code one in my free time, that'd probably answer a couple questions more here.

Comment: @Uds Edited the answer to include a JS snippet that gets rid of those characters. Give it a try [here](http://jsbin.com/alefal/10).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté : Thanks man. Looks like theres another script clashing with this. I have to look into it. Yes, the issue was the funny character. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17427/discussion-between-uds-and-fabricio-matte)

Answer (score 1):

When you copy and paste from JSFiddle, you copy extra characters that are illegal and throw errors.

Yours is on line 49 of your index.html.

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('div').hide();
    $('.' + val).css('display','block');
}).change();​
//Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Also, as *PhillipKregg* pointed out, you have a syntax error. See his answer for details on that.

Comment: @aheren I updated the link but it still doenst work. : http://fitfixtraining.com.au/test/index.html

Comment: @Uds  - you've still got the same error. Instead of copy/pasting, try deleting the whole `<script>` tag and typing it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

See this line:

```
 $('.' + val).css('display','block'); }).change();​
```

Get rid of the extra curly brace - }

Comment: isnt it function's closing bracket?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your javascript correctly, therefore it's invalid and not being loaded.

You need to close the select function and the document ready function.